# Understanding the field trace equation $\text{Tr}_{L:K}(\alpha)=[L:K(\alpha)]\text{Tr}_{K(\alpha):K}(\alpha)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, linear-transformations, trace

According to [this](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/154Page/handouts/normtrace.pdf) paper, given the finite field extension $L:K$ and $\alpha\in L$, we define the trace $\text{Tr}_{L:K}(\alpha)$ as the trace of the linear transformation $$m_\alpha:L\rightarrow L:x\mapsto \alpha x$$

The paper then argues that "if we build a $K$-basis of $L$ by first picking a basis of $K(\alpha )$ and then picking a basis of $L$ over $K(\alpha )$,
we get a ‘block’ matrix for $m_{\alpha}$ consisting of $[L : K(\alpha )]$ copies of the smaller square matrix for $m_{\alpha} : K(\alpha) \rightarrow K(\alpha)$
along the main diagonal, so
$\text{Tr}_{L:K}(\alpha)=[L:K(\alpha)]\text{Tr}_{K(\alpha):K}\big(\alpha\big)$".

I understand the idea of constructing a basis for $L$ over $K$ in the manner they describe, but I do not understand at all where this 'block' matrix comes from. In fact, it seems to me that for any $\vec{l}\in L$, regardless of our choice of basis, we have

$$\alpha \text{I}_n\vec{l}=\alpha\vec{l}$$

where $\text{I}_n$ is the identity matrix of dimension $n$. So that $\text{Tr}_{L:K}(\alpha)=n\alpha$.

---

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: See the displayed equation of block matrices in the middle of page 5 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm2.pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're wrong.

1. If the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ is $f(x)=x^s+a_1x^{s-1}+\ldots+a_s$,
   then the basis $K(\alpha):K$ can be chosen as $1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{s-1}$.
2. Let $u_1,\ldots,u_t$ be a basis of extension $L:K(\alpha)$.
3. Then the basis of $L:K$ is $\alpha_iu_j$, $0\leq i\leq s-1$, $1\leq j\leq t$.
4. On each block $u_j,\alpha u_j,\ldots,\alpha^{s-1}u_j$ of the basis,
   the linear transformation $m_\alpha$ acts as a shift
   $$
   m_\alpha(u_j)=\alpha u_j,\
   m_\alpha(\alpha u_j)=\alpha^2 u_j,\
   \ldots,
   m_\alpha(\alpha^{s-1} u_j)=\alpha^s u_j=-(a_s+\ldots+\alpha^{s-1}a_1)u_j
   $$
   Therefore the matrix $m_\alpha$ in this basis has a block form.
   On the diagonal there are $s\times s$-blocks of the form
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix}
   0&0&\ldots & -a_s\\
   1&0&\ldots &-a_{s-1}\\
   0&1&\ldots &-a_{s-2}\\
   \ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
   0&0&\ldots&-a_1\end{pmatrix}
   $$
   and there are $t$ blocks of this kind.
   It follows that $\operatorname{Tr}_{L:K}(m_\alpha)=-a_1t\in K$.

**Addition.**
Your formula is correct in the following form
$\operatorname{Tr}_{L:L}m_\alpha=\alpha$. But in this form it is of little interest.
To define a trace over $K$, we must define the matrix of multiplication by $\alpha$
in a basis $L$ over $K$ and then
the matrix coefficients necessarily lie in $K$, and hence the
trace lies in $K$.

**Edit.** Corrected the matrix and formula for the trace. Thanks @Leo.

Comment: I see. One small thing though, shouldn't the matrix be transposed? So that the $i$-th element of the basis would be sent to the $i$-th column vector of the matrix. For example $u_j=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \alpha u_j$, or so that $\alpha ^{s-1}u_j = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} -a_s \\ -a_{s-1} \\ \vdots \\ -a_1 \end{pmatrix} = \alpha ^su_j$.

Comment: I completely agree with you. This is my mistake. I will try to correct it.